# Как добавить элемент в начало списка Java?

Tags: java, списки

Пробовал с имя_списка.add() и имя_списка.set(). Результат нулевой.

```
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        list.add(i, r.readLine());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: покажи подробный код (добавь в вопрос, отредактировав его). скорее всего ты делаешь что-то не так

Answer (score 5):

```
имя_списка.add(0,элемент_списка);
```

UPDATE:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    list.add(0, r.readLine());
}
for (String str : list){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Так как появились подробности, дополню: если в задаче нет чёткой привязки на интерфейс `List`, то правильнее использовать класс [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) c его [LIFO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO).

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    stack.push(r.readLine());
}
while (!stack.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
```

Comment: `add` тоже должен работать. так что ответ мимо, пока не известен изначальный код автора

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `add` без индекса добавляет в конец

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Впринципе согласен и на ответ не тянет, но `add()` сработает только на пустом списке

Comment: @defaultlocale мм. да, не заметил что в начало. однако все равно неизвестно как ТС пытался это сделать

Comment: Отправил часть кода

Comment: @Никита тебе надо писать `list.add(0, r.readLine());` в итоге, а не `list.add(i, r.readLine());`

Comment: @Никита хотя тут от задачи зависит. например в чем идея добавлять всё время в начало?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский 
 
Требования:
1. Объяви переменную типа список строк и сразу проинициализируй ee.
2. Программа должна считывать 10 строк с клавиатуры и добавлять их в список.
3. Программа должна добавлять строки в начало списка.
4. Программа должна выводить список на экран, каждое значение с новой строки.

Comment: @Никита ясненько